# Does anyone recognize this program icon?

Tags: icons

I have noticed recently on my Windows 7 system, that this program icon (see the link below) appears among the list of running programs in Windows' Alt+Tab Task-Switcher. It appears with no program-name label. (I suspect it may be a remnant of a program that was uninstalled, but not completely.) Nothing happens when I try to switch to that program in the task-switcher, and it does not show up among the running applications in Windows' Task Manager. It is always there, even just after a reboot.

Sorry about the quality of the image (especially the background, which is a product of the camera - the original has no background). This image was the best I could get with my mobile phone camera. Because it only shows up when using Task-Switcher, it was impossible to take a conventional screenshot using the normal methods. Google's reverse image search does not find any matches, possibly due to the poor image quality.

Unknown Windows Program-Icon:

[image]

Comment: It looks like the standard .vb net app icon from Visual Studio... See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036634/how-to-change-a-program-icon-in-taskbar-vb-net

Answer (score 3):

It's a default icon for Visual Basic (or Visual Studio in general?) programs:

http://checktechno.blogspot.com/2012/12/extract-icon-from-file.html

Comment: Thanks, and thanks also to  Spittin' Big Nasty IT for your answers. That is indeed the icon I'm seeing. I've never installed VB (not even the runtime) on this computer, though there are definitely traces of it on my system. It may be part of Microsoft.NET Framework. In any case, I'm now wondering why it's showing up (especially with no text label) in the Task Switcher. Is that normal behaviour? Nothing in the system tray looks like it is a likely user of it, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Visual Basic 6 (which is the only version that can run on modern versions of Windows) **is not** part of the .NET Framework.  Windows 7 has built-in support for Visual Basic and thus has the icons already.  The icon could be used for VBScript files

Comment: @Moongazer While "thanks" in great and nice, don't forget to accept the answer. That's what "accepting answers" is for. To denote that it solved your issue (and bring some points to user giving it).